# SQL return false if timestamp is less than 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application where users can vote for a post, but I want to limit them so they can only vote once per 24 hours.

How would I select the rows from the database to check if the timestamp field is older than 24 hours?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to do it, but I want to query the database and only select a row if the field which is a timestamp was added over 24 hours ago to the current time.

Comment: Surely you know how to use google, there are alot of examples like this on the web and even on stackoverflow itself. When you created the question, did you look at questions about this subject asked in the past?

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid, albeit a bit short question. This platform would be quite empty if it only contained information that is not available elsewhere. @Tikkes You might want to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are looking for [mysql's date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Here as an example for you to expand:

```
… WHERE timestamp_column < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
```